# Invalid Method Declaration? Return Type Required?

Tags: java, button, bluej

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
//----------I could just do import java.awt.*; and import java.swing.*; but, when the program get larger, this could cause glitches, so it's better not to----------
public class Gui extends JFrame{

public class QA //THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING THE ERROR MESSAGE
{
    private int x;
         private JButton reg;
         private JButton custon;

         public Gui();
    public QA()
    {
```

I coppied code from a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6iV-v_m0z0w), but I'm not sure what the problem is. Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Why do you have a `Gui` constructor inside the `QA` class? And where are the constructor bodies?

Comment: You have "public class GUI" and inside that, "public class QA". Do you really mean to use nested classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`public Gui();` doesn't have any return type and doesn't have any implementation and it shouldn't be inside `QA`

move this constructor method up to `Gui` class

```
public class Gui extends JFrame{

public Gui(){}

public class QA //THIS IS WHERE I'M GETTING THE ERROR MESSAGE
{
...
}
```